# How do I require login authentication before the main app loads with Netbeans Generated code?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, passwords

Heads up I am very new to Java, 2 days experience so far. I am trying to require my program to show my login form, which is a separate class, and show my main application after authentication is validated. The login class has a isAuth() method that returns a boolean.

So, in netbeans the main app generates the application in 4 stages shown by the following.

```
@Override protected void startup() {
    show(new login()); // loads frame only...

    show(new Snap_multitabletestView(this));
}

/**
 * This method is to initialize the specified window by injecting resources.
 * Windows shown in our application come fully initialized from the GUI
 * builder, so this additional configuration is not needed.
 */
@Override protected void configureWindow(java.awt.Window root) {
}

/**
 * A convenient static getter for the application instance.
 * @return the instance of Snap_multitabletestApp
 */
public static Snap_multitabletestApp getApplication() {
    return Application.getInstance(Snap_multitabletestApp.class);
}

/**
 * Main method launching the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //my guess is login logic would go here?        
    launch(Snap_multitabletestApp.class, args);
}
```

So, essentially I am having a hard time figuring out the syntax for keeping the main app locked/hidden until the login has been verified.

Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to design the program such that your "main program" has no user interface at all.

When it launches the application launches a log on screen and waits until that screen returns. (Maybe look up threads and the `join` operation). Once the screen returns, if successful it launches your other GUI, otherwise it quits or re-opens the logon screen with an error.

A quick pseudocode walkthrough....
main launches -> Creates new thread that shows Logon GUI -> main thread `join`s the GUI thread -> GUI thread exits with return code set -> main thread checks return code for success/failure -> proceed to real GUI if successful -> re-open logon otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

On startup do you have to show both the screens? You can show the login screen and on proper authentication you can enable/show the other screens.

Comment: No, It currently displays 2 windows now, and I only want the login screen displayed on startup, and with authentication the login will close and launch the main application.